# BrainTreePayments create new payment method

Tags: node.js, braintree

I am going through the BrainTreePayments documentation page and I came across the Payment Methods. The documentation says "To create a new payment method for an existing customer, the only required attributes are the customer ID and payment method nonce."

```
gateway.paymentMethod.create({
  customerId: "12345",
  paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient
}, function (err, result) { });
```

The question is

1) How do we create a new payment method for a new customer without payment method nonce?
2) How do we verify the validity of an existing payment method?

Comment: You can't create a payment method without including payment method information—what's your stumbling block about nonces?

Comment: @hollabaq From my understanding of the code provided, without the nonces, you cannot create a payment method. So how can I create a new payment method for a new customer? Maybe my flow of thinking is wrong, you can correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

1) A payment method is like a container to *store* payment information in your Vault, whereas the [payment method nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#payment-method-nonce) is a way to *deliver* payment information to Braintree. You use a payment method nonce to deliver payment information to create payment methods, transactions, etc. A payment method can be referenced to generate a payment method nonce from stored payment information, but the payment method must store something. You can't create an empty payment method.

2) To verify an existing payment method, use ['PaymentMethod.update()'](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node#card-verification) and include 'verify_card' in your options. If you have enabled [fraud tools](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/card-verification#enabling-card-verification) in your control panel, newly created payment methods for credit cards will be verified before they are stored in the Vault. Cards that are not valid will not be stored and you will receive an [error response](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/node).

Comment: my use case for my product will be using both Credit Card and PayPal Vault. So should i create both Credit Card and PayPal Vault first then create a payment method?

Comment: @ShawnAng Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this. Please write into support@braintreepayments.com